# RxJava - add headers in a sorted list of emitted items

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have a list of items and emit it:

```
Observable<Item> items = Observable.fromIterable(list);
```

Now I want to have a second observable that inserts headers. If a header must be inserted or not can be decided by comparing two consecutive items. Any ideas how to do that?

Logic is like following:

- compare two consecutive items
- if they need different headers, add a new header item between them
- if not, just emit the items

I need something similar to `scan` but the operator must emit the input items + an optional header item...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buffer with a sliding window and do a flatMap over the overlapping windows to insert headers/separators between items:

```
Observable.just(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14)
.buffer(2, 1)
.flatMapIterable(v -> {
    if (v.size() <= 1) {
        return v;
    }
    if (v.get(1) - v.get(0) > 1) {
        return Arrays.asList(v.get(0), 1000);
    }
    return Collections.singletonList(v.get(0));
})
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very good. Is my assumption true: the statement `if (v.size() <= 1)` is true for the very first item, correct?

Comment: It is there for the very last item as the number of items in total could be odd and `buffer` will emit a 1 element list in that case.